# Is there a way to specify which Unicode format is used in unicode encoding in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

so I'd like to encode some values in Unicode in my python 2.7 script.  I'd like to know if I can specify which type of Unicode to use, i.e UTF-8 vs UTF-32.  Apart from that are there any limitations as to which encodings are supported in python 2.7, and how is the default encoding determined?

Comment: You mean encoding of source file or encoding of python's string in memory?

Comment: a python string

Answer (score 0):

So, first things first: you should be using Python 3, not Python 2.

The handling of text and unicode is the major difference between the two versions of the language, and the real reason they had to do incompatible changes, and it is *much*, *much* more straightforward in Python 3.

This means to talk about unicode in Python 2 you have to understand certain things - unicode is used to represent *text*: characters regardless of the underlying representation these characters have.

In Python 2 programs, all text typed in the program itself have to be typed with "u" prefixed strings, like `u"..."` or `u'...'` - otherwise the strings are considered "byte strings" - just like one have in C code. (Alternativelly, one can place `from __future__ import unicode_literals` in the first or second line of the file, so this is done automatically.

Otherwise, all data read into the program, either from text files, database connections, inbound HTTP requests, will usually get as *byte* strings in Python2, and have to explicitly converted to text-strings (that is "unicode objects" in Python 2 speak) before being processed. This is done by calling the bytes-string `.decode` method - and you pass as the first parameter to it the encoding name used for those bytes. That is, if you have data you have read from an `utf-8` encoded file, it can be decoded to text by doing:

```
data = data.decode("utf-8")  #  and so on for other encodings.
```

Also, if you are typing any non-ascii character in the source code of a Python2 file, regardless of it being inside a string (or, inside a comment, for example), you have to declare the file encoding in the first line of the file.

That is done with a Python comment that is treated in a special way by the language parser - the first LoC should contain:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

(of course, you should type the encoding actually used by your program-editor to store the file. Also, some variants on this marking are allowed, as writting "coding" instead of encoding, the ":" being optional, and so on)

So - what I've described in the previous *5* paragraphs takes place automatically in Python 3. But if you followed up so far, you now have a program running with text to be handled. As you can perceive, you did not mention in your question *how* you are inputing this text you want to encode in different ways.

So, just as you did explicitly convert the input bytes to in memory unicode strings, now you can use the `.encode` method to convert the text back to whatever text-encoding you want.

If you have some text that you want to write in a text-file encoded in utf-32 little endian, you do:

```
with open("myfile.txt", "wt") as file_:
    file_.write(data.encode("utf-32 LE"))
```

The valid text codecs are listed, as per Eran's answer at:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Now, if you do some tests with this and succeed, you'd better do *two* things before proceeding any further:

- switch to use Python 3.  Python 2 is real obsolete at this point - check if it is not already installed in your system by typing "python3" instead of just "Python". If it is not, just install it - it can live side-by-side with Python2

  - Read [this article](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/), to get a grasp on what really goes on whn we talk about unicode in encodings. (The author, Joel, is the founder of Stackoverflow itself, and the article is from 2003)

Answer (score -2):

In python 2, strings are by default ASCII. You can decode them and re-encode them.
supported encodings can be found here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Here's an example:

```
a = "my string"  # a is ASCII encoded bytes
b = u"my string"  # b is unicode, not encoded
c = a.decode()  # c is unicode, not encoded, by default decoding ASCII, you can specify otherwise as an argument
d = c.encode('utf-32')  # d is utf-32 encoded bytes
print type(a)  # output: <type 'str'>
print type(b)  # output: <type 'unicode'>
print type(c)  # output: <type 'unicode'>
print type(d)  # output: <type 'str'>
```

Note 1: that in python 3 things are somewhat different.
Note 2: In order to write non-ascii literals in your script (that is if you want to write `a = "☂"` as part of your code, as opposed to having `a` just a variable that contains data you got from somewhere) you have to declare the encoding at the top of the file, more info [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/). And in python 2 only a small subset of unicode characters are accepted in the literal code. (while in memory of course you are not limited).
Note 3: Of course that while unicode type is to you not encoded, internally python keeps it encoded (either as utf-32 if I'm not mistaken). But that's an internal detail that shouldn't affect your code generally speaking.

Comment: The default encoding in Python 2 is ASCII, not UTF-8. `u"..."` creates a Unicode object in memory, but is still subject to Python's interpretation of the *bytes* stored in the file.

Comment: @chepner, you are right about ASCII, I'll fix that. As for about unicode literal, that's my "Note 3"